# disabled all modules output, looking for a way to reable them

Tags: mysql, magento

i have a very simple question, i turned off all module output in magento configuration > advanced > disable module output (i was debugging some annoying bug, and a lack of common sense made me turn off all the core modules)

Now my back-office is completely empty, except header / footer, and i'm looking for a way to re-able the magento's core modules.

Is there any chance i can do it in database ?

Comment: You can find needed records in table `core_config_data` like `advanced/modules_disable_output/%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reenable all the core **Mage** modules by running the following SQL command:

```
UPDATE core_config_data 
SET value = 0
WHERE path LIKE '%advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage%'
AND value = 1
```

**value = 1** is disabled
**value = 0** is enabled